# My class is not working, it's ignoring variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

It doesn't matter where I put the print or the `user1` variable, it gives me different errors. In this setup it gives me `"NameError: name 'user1' is not defined"`. What am I doing wrong?

```
   class gram():

    def __init__(self, username, phone, email, password):

        self.username = username
        self.phone = phone
        self.email = email
        self.password = password

print(user1.username)     

user1 = gram("sdff", "sdfkmds", "wfowjfnw", "fjwknfwnw")

print(user1.username)

gram()
```

Comment: This is because you're using **user1** before actually declaring it in the next line.

Comment: Your edit still didn't remove the line in the incorrect position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class gram():

    def __init__(self, username, phone, email, password):

        self.username = username
        self.phone = phone
        self.email = email
        self.password = password

        # If you want to print username on creation then put it inside __init__()
        #print(self.username)     

user1 = gram("sdff", "sdfkmds", "wfowjfnw", "fjwknfwnw")

print(user1.username)
```

Comment: __init__ method is called automatically when you create an instance of class. So if you want to print something or do something when you create your object like user1. the you can call it. In this case if you want to print the username. you can use print statement inside __init__().

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you are printing `user1.username` twice, and the first time is before you have defined `user1`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one problem in code, leaving the problem in while trying other solutions won't work:

```
class gram():
    def __init__(self, username, phone, email, password):
        self.username = username
        self.phone = phone
        self.email = email
        self.password = password

# user1 has not yet been created, so this won't work
# print(user1.username)     

user1 = gram("sdff", "sdfkmds", "wfowjfnw", "fjwknfwnw")
# This will work
print(user1.username)

# gram requires four elements to call, so this won't work
# gram()
```

Comment: what if I want user 1 and print INSIDE the class, or is that a no-no?

Comment: No, user1 isn't in scope in the class.  If you want to print the username of the class, use `print(self.username)`.  If you want to print the username from inside the class of another instance, pass that instance in.